# Compiling a build.xml file using Ant

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

I recently installed *Ant 1.8.4* and *JasperReports 4.6.0* on my *Ubuntu* machine.

The following environmental variables were set on my account:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/ant/bin

export PATH

export ANT_HOME=/opt/ant

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
```

When I try to run a demo build file in the *JasperReports* demo samples directory using the command `ant` I get the following error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/demo/samples/antcompile/build.xml:3: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/opt/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Any help in solving this problem will be super helpful.

The snippet of *build.xml* file:

```xml
<project name="antcompile" default="test" basedir=".">

    <description>Shows how multiple JRXML files can be compiled in batch mode using ANT.</description>

    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="../../../build/classes"/>
        <fileset dir="../../../lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="runClasspath">
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="../../fonts"/>
        <pathelement location="./build/classes"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="javac" description="Compiles the Java source files used in the report designs.">
        <mkdir dir="./build/classes"/> 
        <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes" debug="true" optimize="false" deprecation="false"/>
    </target> 

    <target name="compile1" description="Compiles report designs specified using the &quot;srcdir&quot; in the &lt;jrc&gt; tag."> <!-- 27 row # -->
        <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
        <jrc 
                srcdir="./reports"
                destdir="./build/reports"
                tempdir="./build/reports"
                keepjava="true"
                xmlvalidation="true">
            <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
            <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
        </jrc>
    </target>
```

Comment: What version of Ant are you using?

Comment: Hello Alex, I'm using Ant 1.8.4

Answer (score 2):

This *Ant* script is using custom task ***jrc***.

As you can see from the snippet below (this is *build.xml* file from the ***jasperreports-4.6.0/demo/samples/antcompile*** folder), this task's definition refers the **classpath** from the same build file.

```xml
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="../../../build/classes"/>
    <fileset dir="../../../lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

...

<taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

You should check the ***../../../build/classes*** folder (in *JasperReports* package's folder structure which contains samples) - the ***net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask*** class must be there.

In other words you should put this class (or **jasperreports-4.6.0.jar**) to the classpath (*`path id="classpath"`*).

---

Another probable source of your problem is the version of *Ant* package.

You can read about [Project#createTask complains it wouldn't find task componentdef](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50788) issue on *Ant*'s bugtracker and [project.createTask() not working with ant-1.8.2](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/project-createTask-not-working-with-ant-1-8-2-td3385716.html) post.

Comment: .:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/ant-1.7.1.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/dist/jasperreports-4.6.0.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/iText-2.1.7.jar:/opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by changing the following element in my CLASSPATH, /opt/jasperreports-4.6.0/lib/ant-1.7.1.jar to /opt/ant/lib/ant.jar. 
Thanks to Alex for posting the helpful links!
Anjan

Answer (score 0):

You're going have to help us out a bit here...

Are you building JasperReports-4.6.0? Or, are you using JasperReports as part of your `build.xml`? Is this a test `build.xml` demoing JasperReports?

The error says *Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared*, so what is the Ant task in line #37? Is there a  *in the `build.xml`? Does it have a *classpath* defined? If you have a *taskdef*, please let us see what it is, and what the custom task is.*

I'm downloading iReport to see if I can figure out what you're doing, but it's taking 15 minutes. I bet you're supposed to put some jar into `$ANT_HOME/lib`. Maybe that JasperReports or iReport jarfile.

As soon as I can download iReport and see what you're talking about, I'll update my answer.

Meanwhile, include the relevant code around line #35 in your `build.xml` and the `taskdef` task in your `build.xml`.

---

Finished downloading iReport and there is no build.xml file in it. You're going to have to post your code, so we can look at it.

Again, my assumption is that there's some jar file that they assumed you'd stick in `/opt/ant/lib` and didn't.